# i cant run my Deploy.js

Tags: solidity, nodejs

So i currently learn to become web3 developer. so i follow tutorial from yt and i got stuck. I try to run Deploy.js using command PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD = password node Deploy.js. i am using windows 10. And i got this error

```
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD : The term 'PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD = password node Deploy.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

this is my Deploy.js code

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const translate = require("solc/translate");
require('dotenv').config();

async function main() {
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545
  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL);
  // const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,provider);
  const encryptedJson = fs.readFileSync("./.encryptedKey.json", "utf8");
  
  let wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync(encryptedJson, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD);
  wallet = await wallet.connect(provider);
  const abi = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi", "utf8");
  const binary = fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin","utf8");
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
  // Getting number from SimpleStorage contract
  const currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
  console.log(`Current Favorite Number: ${currentFavoriteNumber.toString()}`);
  const transactionResponse = await contract.store("7");
  const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1); 
  const updatedFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
  console.log(`Updated transaction number is: ${updatedFavoriteNumber}`);

  // console.log("Let's deploy with only transaction data!");
  // const nonce = await wallet getTransactionCcount();
  // const tx = {
  //   nonce: nonce,
  //   gasPrice: 20000000000,
  //   gasLimit: 100000,
  //   to: null,
  //   value: 0,
  //   data: "0x60"(I delete some of it since i think its not relevant aka commented)
  //   chainId: 1337, 
  // };
  // const sentTxResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
  // await sentTxResponse.wait(1);
  // console.log(sentTxResponse);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I think there is no problem with encryptedKey.json. But if that code is needed i will post it too.
thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `.env` file, and declare `PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD` inside the file.

**.env**

```
PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD="YourPrivateKeyPassword"
```

Comment: yes according to the video that i follow the private_key_password need to be deleted since we dont want another person to look into our private key and the password to open the private key. I try with the private_key_password deleted and with private_key_password exist on the code but still encounter the same error

Comment: make sure you have run `source .env` in terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will try it. But for now i just skip it and go on with the course